# Is this a continuous function?

Tags: functions

I've got a function:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
{\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}}, &\text{if }x \neq 1 ,  x \neq-1 \\
\\\frac{1}{2}, &\text{if }x = 1.
\end{cases}$$

During my calculations I get that both limits at $1$ are equal and the value in this point is also equal to limits.
Can somebody tell me why this function isn't continuous as the answer suggests?

Comment: It's not continuous at $x=-1$.

Comment: Is $y$ there a typo or not?

Comment: It is indeed continuous on its domain. It has no continuous extension to the whole $\Bbb R^2$, though.

Comment: It is continuous on its domain (which does not include $-1$); nor can it be defined at $-1$ so as to be continuous there.

Comment: So assuming what you have said. It is not continous in -1 which doesn't belong to the domain, which means, that this function isn't continous? But what is the type of this classification of discontinuities?

Comment: sounds like there is a typo

Comment: Yes, it was, sorry!

Comment: @Mikkey A rather informal approach is to look at it this way: If you can trace the entire curve with the pencil without lifting the pencil from the paper, it is continuous. (For a hole in the graph, that means you have to lift). Now for $x=1$, this has been taken care of, but for $x=-1$ there is a vertical asymptote which is never going to make a function continuous.